# MonoGame not able to find dylib files, throwing DllNotFoundException

Tags: mono, xamarin, monogame

I have a project using MonoMac in Xamarin Studio. I'm using `[DllImport ("rlimit")]` to access a .dylib file. However, even though I have mapped `rlimit` to `rlimit.dylib`, a `DllNotFoundException` is still thrown.

The .dylib files are in the project and should be accessible, however they cannot be found.

I'm guessing that the files are either in the wrong place, or they aren't being detected for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the dylib anywhere mono can find it.

You can find out where mono looks for native libraries by doing this:

```
export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug
export MONO_LOG_MASK=dll
mono yourprogram.exe
```

and verbose lookup output will be printed to the terminal. On my system mono looks first in the directory where the executable is, so putting the dylib there is probably the easiest. Then mono asks the system to find the dylib (by trying to open it without a path). The system typically looks in /usr/lib and maybe a few other places (this is of course system-dependent), but in any case you can add a path for the system to look in by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to that path. In this case you'll do this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/dylib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
mono yourprogram.exe
```

Note that you do not need the .dllmap, mono will automatically append the appropiate suffix depending on the platform (.dylib on Mac, .so on Linux and .dll on Windows).